# What is the best way to transform a specific literal expression in a mathematical expression using logical notation?

Tags: logic, notation

I am having a hard time finding the correct solution for the following problem, right now.

**"New trade agreement means Dollar and Yuan will rise and fall together"**

How should I express this statement mathematically? Given that:

`D: the Dollar is strong, Y: the Yuan is strong T:New US-China trade agreement is signed`

Which one would be *correct/more accurate?*

`T⇒ [(D ∧ Y) ∧  ¬(D ∧ Y)]` or `T ⇒ [(D ⇒ Y) ∧ (Y ⇒ D)]`

Thank you :)

Comment: Your first option `[(D ∧ Y) ∧  ¬(D ∧ Y)]` contains two errors.

Answer (score 1):

When reading this you want to make sure what the negation will tell you. When you proceed with DeMorgan's Law with $\lnot (D \land Y)$ it turns into $\lnot D \lor \lnot Y$ which means the dollar or the yuan will fall, which is not what we are wanting.

Instead we want: $T \to (D \land Y) \lor (\lnot D \land \lnot Y),$ this is saying that "If the agreement is signed then the dollar and yuan will rise together or fall together." Reason I put "or" is that it'll rise together or fall together, but cannot rise and fall at the same time together.

Comment: Not all heroes wear capes, :) thank you!

Comment: If you could accept the answer that would be awesome :-)

Comment: I couldn't upvote your answer because of my insufficient reputation points, if this is not what you mean, how do I accept your answer? (I really don't know how to do it)